# Is it possible for sphinx autodoc to deal with dynamic attributes?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, bravado

I'm using Bravado to generate an API client for an OpenAPI endpoint. I've extended the `SwaggerClient` to deal with some pagination issues. The client overrides `__getattr__` and `__dir__`, so any instantiated client will provide attributes mapping to whatever the swagger specification contains.

Is it possible to get sphinx to generate documentation for these dynamically added attributes?